# PHP need to output &#39; instead of '

Tags: javascript, php, apostrophe

I have an issue with jbar where it's outputting a ' and causing the javascript to break. My code is:

```
<div class="jbar" data-init="jbar" data-jbar='{
"message" : "<?php echo $myann->getValue("heading", 0); ?>",
"button"  : "<?php echo $myann->getValue("buttonText", 0); ?>",
"url"     : "<?php echo $myann->getValue("buttonURL", 0); ?>",
"state"   : "open"
}'></div>
```

If I manually type in:

```
"message" : "My name's test",
```

This breaks still. If I type in:

```
"message" : "My name&#39;s test",
```

This works!

So... How can I get the php echo to use the ' instead of the '? I've tried htmlspecialchars and addslashes but neither work.

Thanks.

Comment: You tried it like this? `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($myann->getValue("heading", 0), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks machineaddict... that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

> "'" (single quote) becomes ''' (or ') only when ENT_QUOTES is set.

So

```
echo htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `json_encode()`:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "message" => $myann->getValue("heading", 0),
    "button"  => $myann->getValue("buttonText", 0),
    "url"     => $myann->getValue("buttonURL", 0),
    "state"   => "open",
);
?>
<div class="jbar"
     data-init="jbar"
     data-jbar='<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>'></div>
```

Comment: The `'` character has no special meaning in a string in JSON, so that won't help at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This still resulted in the javascript plugin to not work. The suggestion from machineaddict above worked however. Thanks for your time.